# Strange behavior between Windows Server 2003 and 2008 DNS resolution

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2003

I have a wierd issue which i troubleshoot and found to be due to OS differences. On my 2003 server i can ping the following :

- hostname.childdomain.example.com ( Passed )
- hostname ( Passed )
- hostname.child ( Passed )

On my 2008 server :

- hostname.childdomain.example.com ( Passed )
- hostname ( Passed )
- hostname.child ( Failed )

Unix platform :

- hostname.childdomain.example.com ( Passed )
- hostname ( Passed )
- hostname.child ( Failed )

DNS suffix on Windows Servers :

- childdomain.example.com
- example.com

The DNS suffix on both 2003 and 2008 servers are the same. I have verified by testing that due to the DNS suffix i am able to ping hostname.child on my windows 2003 server. The DNS servers are in Unix platform. The AD objects are in the same OU. The closet i could find online with regards to this issue is the following article :

http://networkadminkb.com/KB/a253/windows-2008-append-parent-suffixes-the-primary-dns.aspx

But no matter what i change i cannot get the same behavior on 2008 server. Any help or direction given is greatly appericiated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you perform an ipconfig /flushdns on both, then ping all three again after which run ipconfig /displaydns can you post back the results?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response and feedback. Done this during troubleshooting few hours back but to no avail. The behaviour is across all servers as I sample a few servers to conclude this. I have not tried the ipconfig /displaydns , will try and feedback soon.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. Solution to this problem can be found in the article below :

http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2009/04/16/dns-client-name-resolution-behavior-in-windows-vista-vs-windows-xp.aspx

http://www.networksteve.com/windows/topic.php/Win_7_VPN_nslookup_resolves_-_ping_does_not_resolve/?TopicId=43146&Posts=0